# passing data to detail page flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

hello I'm new to flutter I want to know
how can I pass the movie details data when the user clicks on a movie to moviedetail() from firebase?
I want when a user clicks on a movie the exact movie info will display in the moviedetail() page
I've tried using the future builder and I still can't pass the data to moviedetails()

here's my code

```
import 'package:cinema_project/screens/moviedetail.dart';
import 'package:cinema_project/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowingPage extends StatefulWidget {



  final String id;
  ShowingPage(this.id);



  @override
  _ShowingPageState createState() => _ShowingPageState();
}

class _ShowingPageState extends State<ShowingPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("nowshowing").snapshots(),
          builder: (context , snapshot ){
                         if(snapshot.data == null) return Loading();
             return GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 20/30,
          mainAxisSpacing: 30.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0
        ),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length , itemBuilder: (context,index){ 
            DocumentSnapshot showing = snapshot.data.documents[index]; 
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_){
                return MovieDetail();
              }));
          },
                  child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: NetworkImage(showing['img'])),
                                boxShadow:[ 
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                                    blurRadius: 4,
                                    color: Colors.black26,
                                  )
                                ]
                              ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        
                      ),
        );
  }
); });}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple pass data in constructor.

Here you can do this

**Showing Page class**

```
onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_){
                return MovieDetail(
                 movieData : snapshot.data.documents[index];
            }));},
```

**On MovieDetail Page**
Define your variable in the constructor and just use like widget.movieData['movieName']

```
dynamic moviedata;
MovieDetail({Key key,this.moviedata}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: if you found this answer usefull upvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_){
                return MovieDetail(
                 movieData : snapshot.data.documents[index];
            }));

//MovieDetail Page
//Create a constructor and retrieve the value.
var movieData;
MovieDetail(this.movieData)
```

You can pass data with the help of `Constructor` but it is not preferred because when your app runs the whole widget tree re-builds and it is not needed to rebuild whole widgets, when only one widget is changed.

So, Instead of  `Constructor` you can use `Provider` a commonly used state management technique in flutter https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options